# setTimeout calling function inside function - Scope-Issue

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

So, the problem is that I have a function inside a function that needs to be called by setTimeout.
That doesn't work however because setTimeout will assume that the function it calls has the root as its' scope.

Any idea how I could solve this without changing the scope of the function?

Edit:

Here is what I mean:

```
function general(){
    function saysomething(){
        console.log('hi there');
    }
setTimeout("saysomething();", 1000);
}
```

The setTimeout fails..

Comment: What? Provide example code or clarify what are you asking about.

Comment: First argument of setTimeout requires you to specify a function object, not string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function general(){
    function saysomething(){
        console.log('hi there');
    }
    setTimeout(saysomething, 1000);
}
```

Comment: The scope chain of a JavaScript function is determined when the function is defined. By defining the callback function inside the body of `general`, you are ensuring that the callback function will be able to reference all the other variables defined inside of `general`, namely `saysomething`.

Comment: In other words, Ben is using a closure to save a reference to the saysomething function.

Answer (score 3):

Not positive this is what you mean but you can pass the variables when you call the function in the setTimeout

```
function f1(){
    var a='1';
    var b='b';
    setTimeout(function(){f2(a,b);},1000)

}

function f2(a,b){
      alert(a + b);
}

f1();
```